# What am I approving with this button on the review edit page?

Tags: support

A user edited one of my questions, and two other community members reviewed and rejected the change:

[image: Approve - what?]

I then got a notification in my inbox, and was shown my post, in diff view, with the box shown above on top of it.

What I don't quite understand is: what am I approving when I hit that blue button?

1. the original edit?
2. the rejection of that edit?
3. something else?

Comment: It overrides the community review and accepts and applies the suggested edit...

Comment: [Related issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296166/164356) - The approve button approves the edit. If you want to reject it as the other reviewers have done, you need to do nothing.

Comment: It kiiiinda looks like you would be approving of the rejection to me. That does look awfully confusing